# Magento2 - How to pass query parameter in curl get method

Tags: magento2, api, jquery, curl

I have a curl request example, it is working once I'm checking it with command line.

> curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/search -u secret key:
> **--data-urlencode** **query="status:'succeeded' AND metadata['order #']:'1000210589'"** -G

I'm trying to convert this code in Magento. I have to use the GET method. I would like to know how we can pass these following options in Magento code.

****--data-urlencode****

**query="status:'succeeded' AND metadata['order #']:'1000210589'"***

If you know something, please let me know your comments and suggestions. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I suggest to install [Stripe PHP bindings](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) library with composer and use it for communications with Stripe

```php
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'YOUR_SECRET'
);
$stripe->paymentIntents->search([
  'query' => 'status:\'succeeded\' AND metadata[\'order #\']:\'1000210589\'',
]);
```